# Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul" not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, code-coverage, grunt-contrib-jasmine

Here is my grunt config file - https://github.com/mdarif/JavaScript-Boilerplate/blob/1.3/GruntFile.js

It's not loading the module - `grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul` and getting `Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul" not found. Is it installed?`

Loading the grunt tasks like `require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);`

Hope someone can help quickly!

Answer (score 2):

I have to install `'load-grunt-tasks'` package to load multiple grunt tasks excludes `grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul` rather than '`matchdep`' package then given code works like charm.

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {
  pattern: ['grunt-*', '!grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul']
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. This solved jasmine-istanbul issue that i had.. But i still get TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined for karma js.

Answer (score 0):

as i told you in your other post. just install that module:

```
$ npm install grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul
```

you probably should save it into your package.json, you can do that directly when installing the plugin:

```
$ npm install grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul --save-dev
```

edit: if you use `..('matchdep').filterDev`, it filters the `devDependencies` in your package.json. grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul is missing in your package.json! easiest way to fix that is the second command i gave you above!

Comment: I already have the grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul abailable, seems like it's not loading the grunt module because of the pattern - require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

Comment: see my edit, you need to add it to the package.json!

Comment: It's already there friend - https://github.com/mdarif/JavaScript-Boilerplate/blob/1.3/package.json

Comment: sry, i was missing that you are inside a branch, i used the Gruntfile-Link in your question and have navigated from there (somehow landing in the master branch)